# vue multilanguage. Смена языка по клику

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Товарищи, использую [этот](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-multilanguage) плагин, для перевода сайта на разные языки. Вопрос: как добраться до this.$language, чтобы по клику на кнопку менять ? Я уже все перепробовал

Comment: А в целом перевод работает?

Comment: Да. Могу вставить v-lang и ок

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Из примера к плагину можно сделать так:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <i>{{title}}: </i>
   <button v-lang.language="'PT'" @click="$language = 'pt'"></button>
   <button v-lang.language="'EN'" @click="$language = 'en'"></button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
name: 'lv-menu',
messages: {
 en: {
  title: 'Switch language'
 },
 pt: {
  title: 'Alterar idioma'
 }
},
computed: {
 title() {
  return this.translate(this.$language, 'title')
 }
}
}
</script>
```

Рабочий пример того как это происходит можно получить так.
Клонируем папку к себе на компьютер выполнив команду в консоли

```
git clone git@github.com:leonardovilarinho/vue-multilanguage.git
```

Переходим в папку и устанавливаем необходимые зависимости, выполнив команду в консоли

```
npm run demo:install
```

Запускаем рабочий пример, выполнив команду

```
npm run demo
```